# Caffeine while fasting

Tags: fast-days

May a person take a caffeine tablet during their fast? The tablet would be placed under the tongue and dissolved without drinking any water so no food or water would be ingested.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Swag. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You need to ask a rav who knows you and can ask for details. A fast like today has leniencies that a regular fast doesn't have because it is pushed over from shabbat. Depending how bad you feel, there might or might not be leniencies. Normally tablets that you dissolve are more strict that tablets you swallow or suppositories which are easier to permit (see e.g., second para [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93434/11501) - not same case but shows difference between tablets you suck and those you swallow). But this site doesn't provide personalized halachic recommendations.

Comment: related: [Caffeine pills vs. suppositories on Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64111/caffeine-pills-vs-suppositories-on-yom-kippur) and [Headache remedy on a fast day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20394/headache-remedy-on-a-fast-day)

Comment: relevant: http://matzav.com/can-i-make-my-fast-easier-by-taking-tzom-kal-and-other-supplementsslow-release-medications/ and https://dinonline.org/2017/07/31/taking-caffeine-supplements-on-major-fast-days/

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61562/taking-tylenol-on-a-taanith-defining-ill

Answer (score 1):

Rav Shmuel Kanenetsky in קובץ הלכות ב/ח writes that for aches or pains, even if you are still obligated to fast, it is permissible to take pills on a fast day. One may even take a sip of water to get the pill down as well. [The exception would be Yom Kippur.]